# How to compensate for additional velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Right now I am working on a simple tank AI - it drives through the level and shoots at any enemy objects in range. There's no physics involved except for a constant velocity added to missile's velocity to account for tank's velocity - the code looks like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Time.time - _lastMissileTime < _missileCooldown)
    {
        return;
    }

    Enemy target = GetClosestEnemy();

    if (target == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Vector3 shootDirection = target.transform.position - transform.position;

    Shoot(shootDirection);

    _shotTargets.Add(target);

    _lastMissileTime = Time.time;
    
    _targets.Clear();
}

private Enemy GetClosestEnemy()
{
    foreach (Enemy enemy in _enemies)
    {
        if (_shotTargets.Contains(enemy))
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, enemy.transform.position) > _missileRange)
        {
            continue;
        }

        _targets.Add(enemy);
    }

    if (_targets.Count < 1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    _targets.Sort((x, y) => Vector3.Distance(x.transform.position, transform.position).CompareTo(Vector3.Distance(y.transform.position, transform.position)));

    return _targets[0];
}

private void Shoot(Vector3 direction)
{
    direction.Normalize();
    
    Missile missile = Instantiate(_missilePrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.LookRotation(direction));

    Vector3 tankVelocity = _mover.Direction * _mover.Speed;
    Vector3 missileVelocity = direction * _missileSpeed + tankVelocity;

    missile.Initialize(missileVelocity, _missileLifetime);
}
```

Here's how it looks like in debug view - yellow lines are for the direct trajectory to target, red lines show the actual trajectory of a missile.

https://gfycat.com/lavishcautiousgrayfox

Now I want to add different levels of experience to my tank AI so veteran level tanks will hit more often - while I could simply remove the tanks velocity from missile velocity calculation for veteran tanks it kinda feels hacky. I would like to determine what direction the tank has to shoot at to compensate for additional velocity but I simply can't figure it out.
I tried simulating the actual shot direction and offseting the direct direction to the target by it but it doesn't work most of the times. I would love any help and ideas!

Comment: This is a rather advanced math question. You have a vector `tankVelocity` of known length and direction and a vector `relativeMissileVelocity` of known length, but unknown direction. You know that `relativeMissileVelocity + tankVelocity` is in the direction `direction`. Now you need to solve for the direction, `missileDirection`, of `relativeMissileVelocity`. 

Note that `relativeMissileVelocity = missileDirection * _missileSpeed` where `missileDirection` is the direction that the tank's gun must point.

I don't know how to solve this math, but hopefully it clarifies the situation.

Comment: I don't quite understand how `_mover.direction` and `direction` are related .. I don't know much about the physics behind it but will a bullet/rocket projectile be so much influenced by the movement of a rather slow moving tank (compared to the projectile velocity)? Couldn't you just say you shoot into the exact target direction but with a random angle offset within a certain range (e.g. +/- 5°) and just lower that range for better AI?